# Using "&times" word in html changes to ×

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code.

HTML Code :

```
<div class="test">&times</div>
```

Javascript:

```
alert($(".test").html());
```

I am getting `×` in alert. I need to get `&times` as result.
Anybody knows or faces this problem? Please update your suggestions.

Comment: It shouldn't give you anything but `&times`. `&times` is not an HTML character, `&times;` is though. **EDIT**: It seems I am wrong - jQuery automatically translates it. `$('<div class="test">&nbsp</div>').html()` reports `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo kinda weird that is.

Comment: @h2ooooooo This has nothing to do with jQuery... http://jsfiddle.net/RaUXC/ Learning HTML before trying to manipulate it with jQuery will solve the problem.

Comment: @bažmegakapa It appears I learned something new today. **WHY** does it translate it though? [W3 reports `The following entity names are used in HTML, always prefixed by ampersand (&) and followed by a semicolon as shown.`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/latin1.html). That's for HTML3 though. I couldn't find any info about characters in HTML4/HTML5 defining this standard. **EDIT**: [I guess I have my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15532395/247893).

Comment: @h2ooooooo [This is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#entities) what I found: `In SGML, it is possible to eliminate the final ";" after a character reference in some cases (e.g., at a line break or immediately before a tag). In other circumstances it may not be eliminated (e.g., in the middle of a word). We strongly suggest using the ";" in all cases to avoid problems with user agents that require this character to be present.`

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yeah, it's just a shame that it doesn't make a difference in chrome/firefox: `$('<div class="test">this is a test of &times and it works</div>').text()` reports `this is a test of × and it works`. [..and of course it's the same in pure HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/RaUXC/1/).

Comment: @h2ooooooo I guess that's acceptable, but this case is strange: http://jsfiddle.net/RaUXC/2/ Well, browsers are historically lenient, otherwise most webpages would not simply work because of the terrible code ;).

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yeah, that's even more weird. It does the same in both Chrome/Firefox/IE5.5/6/7/8/9/10.

Comment: Escape if you're not sure. Webpage interpretation engines very often correct for missing things like end tags, `;`s, `<!doctype>`s, etc.

Comment: X represents multiplication. as in..

2 X 2 = 4

Comment: HTML spec is more of a recommendation, not a binding

Comment: I hate how this is the number one google result for &times;

Comment: I love how this is the number one google result for &times; !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to escape:

```
<div class="test">&amp;times</div>
```

And then read the value using **text()** to get the **unescaped** value:

```
alert($(".test").text()); // outputs: &times
```

Answer (score 84):

You need to escape the ampersand:

```
<div class="test">&amp;times</div>
```

`&times` means a multiplication sign.  (Technically it should be `&times;` but lenient browsers let you omit the `;`.)

Comment: [Character entity references in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html#h-24.1) - good references. [The Brazilian one](http://desenaviegas.com/entities.html#h-24.2.1) shows the symbol as well.

Comment: Thank you for telling `means a multiplication sign`. In programming languages we are habitual of using asterisk (`*`) symbol for multiplication sign. I was wondering how time can map to a cross (or x alphabet symbol) symbol. Then I went back to my primary class education which taught me 3 times 2 is equal to 6 (`3x2=6`). Small x alphabet is *the* actual multiplication sign in mathematics.

Answer (score 9):

`&times;` stands for `×`  in html.
Use  `&amp;times` to get &times

Answer (score 7):

Use the `&#215` code instead of `&times`
Because JSF don't understand the `&times;` code.

Use: `&#215` with `;`

[This link](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html) provides some additional information about the topic.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you did not know that there are different `&` escapes in HTML. [The W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) you can see the codes. `&times` means `×` in HTML code. Use `&amp;times` instead.

Comment: First off, X is not ×. And it's not `&time(s)` (either `&time` or `&times`) it's `&times` *only*.

Comment: that's why I said &time(s), this means with and without an s, and x is x, both is an x

Comment: @RyandeVries: please fix the link provided