# CodeIgniter does not echo &timestamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, timestamp

I never saw this till now
example

```
$test="&timestamp";
echo $test;
```

will output `xtamp` if I put capital `T` then is correct

I try like

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=".$latitude. ",".$longitude. "&".$test. "=".$date."&key=";
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=".$latitude. ",".$longitude. "&timestamp=".$date."&key=";
```

This is output I get

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=44.786568,20.4489216xtamp=1445364621&key=
```

Comment: what happens if you use single quotes, ex. `$test='&timestamp'; echo $test;` ?

Comment: Is it `&timestamp` or `&times;tamp`? View the source of the page.

Comment: what exactly you need there??

Comment: output is xtamp and  source says &timestamp

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i try to get timezone from gmap api this is curl url but still even on welcome controller i get same output problem

Comment: You really should be using http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php to build your query. It will prevent mistakes like this. $test is seeing &times(X) as a special character.

Comment: I didnt get you. You want to get timezone of user??

Comment: @Philip Thanks for answer (i am n..b ) i should  go for coffee:)

Comment: @AleksandarMilisavljevic No worries, coffee helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$test` is not escaped, so it's seeing &times as s special character(x)

```
$query = array(
 'location'  => '',
 'timestamp' => '',
 'key' => ''
);

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?" . http_build_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

&times means a multiplication sign. (Technically it should be × but lenient browsers let you omit the ;.)

Same response here: [Using "&times" word in html changes to ×](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834320/using-times-word-in-html-changes-to-%C3%97)

If you use ('') maybe the PHP doesn't convert the &times to x