# Getting wrong variable name while echoing query string

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');

function generateRandom($length = 24)  
{
 return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
 }
$value = "5000";
$now = new DateTime("now");
$rid = generateRandom();
$current_timestamp = strtotime("now");
$timestamp = "&timestamp";  
$valueToHash = "rid='$rid'&value='$value'&timestamp=".$now->getTimestamp();
echo $valueToHash; 
die;
```

When i am echoing $valueToHash output is -

```
rid='1f7cde02bd050f17e29a4c0f42e55bae96e4543a87133921'&value='5000'×tamp=1530082495
```

but output should be like-

```
rid='1f7cde02bd050f17e29a4c0f42e55bae96e4543a87133921'&value='5000'&timestamp=1530082495
```

Need help in this..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "&times" word in html changes to ×](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834320/using-times-word-in-html-changes-to-%c3%97)

Comment: that function for generating a random string is very slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're outputting raw text on an html page.

The result is that, at a certain point, you're printing `&timestamp`, which actually contains an HTML entity (`&times`) which, guess what, gets interpreted and output as `×`.

If you don't need to actually display this but only use it inside, say, the `href` attribute of an `a` element, you can disregard the problem and leave it as it is.