# registered symbol is killing me

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a cell in my database that holds a text like this `Intel&reg;`

and also I have a checkbox that has a value of `Intel&reg;`

so when I send the checkbox value in a query to php the query ends up like this

`SELECT something from products WHERE company="Intel(®)";`

I put the `'Intel&reg;'` in my database because in somewhere else I'm echoing it out so I hope you understand what's going on

one more time the value of the checkbox is `Intel&reg;` but when I put this value in a query the query ends up like this
`SELECT * from products WHERE company="Intel(®)"`

Comment: sorry if I explained it poorly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish? What's your final goal?

Comment: If you are echoing your query in the browser you will see the symbol.  Try view source on the page and see what is there.

Comment: Try to replace & by &amp; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532252/why-is-reg-being-rendered-as-without-the-bounding-semicolon

Comment: He wants to send the code of the registred character, not the character itself. The question was juste a bit poorly written. I think.

Comment: Why do you need to store ® as &reg;?

Comment: &reg; is a special character

Comment: Try encoding the string with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It will encode special characters back to HTML Entities.

Comment: ® has no special meaning in either html or sql. You can safely store and display it as-is.

Comment: Alexandre TryHard Leblanc is exactly right, guys thanks a million I'm trying your ways right now to see what'll happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the string you're sending to your SQL statement, pass it through [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) first.

Comment: It's usually to be a better idea to do this when displaying data and not storing HTMLized data in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Take look first to PHP Manual:

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";
$a = htmlentities($orig);
$b = html_entity_decode($a);
echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the checkbox is "Intel®" not "Intel&reg;".

"&reg;" is simply one way to represent the ® symbol in HTML. If you want the value to be "Intel&reg;" you need to escape the ampersand using "&amp;"

Storing html encoded values in a database leads to all kinds of issues like this, so I would consider whether you need to store the escaped value at all.

Comment: It didn't work, I tied to put stuff like this in checkbox value "Intel&Friends" came out "Intel", tried "Int&elblah_blah_blah" came out "Int" but thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Did you use "Intel&Friends" or "Intel&amp;Friends"? "Intel&Friends" is not valid html.

Comment: No I used &amp; as well but it didn't work, I don't know the whole thing seems odd to me, "intel&amp;reg;" -> "intel" or "me&amp;my&ampfriend;" -> "me" but I should've explained the situation better because the query gets done in a function and the value of this input is stored in an array inside another array so what I'm trying to say is  it's a whole mess of crap

Comment: (timed out to edit the comment Sorry) No I used &amp; as well but it didn't work, I don't know the whole thing seems odd to me, "intel&amp;reg;" -> "intel" or "me&amp;my&ampfriend;" -> "me" but I used htmlentities right when I move the value into a $query variable and the whole thing works now. Anyway I think I should've explained the situation better because the query gets done in a function and the value of this input is stored in an array inside another array so what I'm trying to say is that it's a whole mess of crap.