# Login to page with CURL

Tags: php, curl

I have the problem with login to the website using CURL. I read the session ID but to use it, I have to reload the page, which is associated with the change. How can I dynamically use the current session id?

```
     <?php
    $post = 'login=testowe12&ampregister=0&password=testowe12&cookie_check=1&_xfToken=&redirect='.urlencode("http://gsmx.co");

    $handle = curl_init('http://gsmx.co/logowanie/login');
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);     
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: gsmx.co',
    'Content-Length: 93',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Origin: http://gsmx.co',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer: http://gsmx.co/login',
    'Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'));
    //'Cookie: xf_session='.$cookie["xf_session"].'; GCSCU_770734409090_H2=C=770734409090.apps.googleusercontent.com:S=81bef9fa0c3fbdaac13c33f8b709fc73474d3562.kvhqgGncJscCDSvW.7dde:I=1403792615:X=1403879015'));
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $output = curl_exec($handle);

    preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $output, $cookie);
    parse_str($cookie[1], $cookie);

    echo $cookie["xf_session"].'<br>'.$output;
?>
```

Greetings

Comment: `login=testowe12&ampregister` is obviously wrong, should be `login=testowe12&register`

Comment: It's right, it's Ampersand (&amp = &), i don't use &register, because &reg = ®. ;)

Comment: no you need `;` so `&amp;` is `&` not `&amp` like `&reg;` = `®` not `&reg` ;p

Comment: hmmm... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532252/why-is-reg-being-rendered-as-%C2%AE-without-the-bounding-semicolon .In my case &reg without ; is also true, interesting :P

Comment: also you got random `'`'s causing syntax errors in the headers, for example `'Origin: <a href="http://gsmx.co'"`

Comment: Ahh sorry, I copied this from Notepad++, in editor i have normally code. ;) I don't have any syntax errors in my code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` for this.

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

This will keep all the cookies in `cookie.txt` and while making a new request cookies will be taken from same `cookie.txt` file. This way you'll be able to maintain the session on successive HTTP requests.

Comment: It won't help me, because i will send new request and session id will change. Session id is sent with header.

Comment: Oh, it was simpler than i thought. Why in second link i am not logged?
http://wklej.org/id/1404008/

Comment: Depends on the website. Its better you pass the cookie and also pass the http referer.

Comment: http://wklej.org/id/1404421/ i added cookies and headers, but i can't login to a second website. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain logged in , then use the same cookie file in all the curl requests you make after logging in .