# Is HtmlParser.entityref actually a valid regex for matching html entity references?

Tags: python, html, sgml

This is the code [from](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e106d9368bff/Lib/HTMLParser.py#l19) Python 2.7 [HtmlParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html):

```
entityref = re.compile('&([a-zA-Z][-.a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

Previously, I assumed it to be more like this:

```
entityref = re.compile('&([a-zA-Z][-.a-zA-Z0-9]*);')
```

so it caught me by surprise on some strange data from some strange source.

My use-case is irrelevant; **is there any reason to define the entity reference like HtmlParser?**

---

**irrelevant use-case:** Should anyone wonder, I describe my use-case nevertheless. Please note that I am not trying to solve my use-case anymore. My question is whether HtmlParser's entityref is buggy.

My use-case is similar to this: [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python/925630#925630)

The input data I was speaking about is like this:

```
r'''<foo bar="blah"> asda&Il_'d@m_'<foo rab="halb">'''
```

The intended output from my use-case would have been `r"""a&Il_'d@m_'"""`.

---

**edit** I was trying to compare the regex [to this sgml reference](http://xml.coverpages.org/sgmlsyn/sgmlsyn.htm#P61) and in my understanding the entity reference *should* end with `;` but I'm not that familiar with the topic, so I wanted to ask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532252/why-is-reg-being-rendered-as-%C2%AE-without-the-bounding-semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntactic production for `reference end` reads:

```
[61] reference end =
  ( refc | ;
    RE ) ? (13) CR
```

That means that the following are recognized as *reference end*s:

- A REFerence Close delimiter (`;` in the reference syntax), as you expected
- A Record End
- **Nothing** (note the use of the `?` metacharacter after the close parenthesis, meaning that both REFC and RE are optional)

If *nothing* is used as a reference end, the reference ends at the first non-name character after the name start character, as required by the rules of the *reference recognition mode* that has been entered at the Entity Reference Open delimiter (ERO `&`).

Note also that ERO is only used for the general entity reference production.