# &currency being change to ¤cy=GBP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a really strange issue where a query string I'm generating to send in an email is being changed somehow.

An old app I programmed, creates a URL from various parameters in the database,

```
dim wpret as string = "<a target=_blank href=""https://.......?instId=" & ID 
& "&amount=" & Server.UrlEncode(amount)
& "&currency=" & Server.UrlEncode(paypalcurr) 
& "&desc=Reservation""">Click here to pay with WorldPay</a>"
```

...which should translate to:

...&currency=GBP...

However, what's being sent to the page is:

> ¤cy=GBP

So the URL is malformed with &currency being changed to ¤cy=GBP

Does this make any sense to anyone? The rest of the URL is absolutely fine - it's just the &currency that is being affected.

I should mention too, my emails get relayed through SendGrid.

Thanks for any insights.

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to HTML-encode the `&` character as `&amp;`.

```
Dim str = "<a target=""_blank"" href=""https://....?instId=" & ID & "&amp;amount=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(amount) & "&amp;currency=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(paypalcurr) & etc
```

Comment: That would only hold true if the ampersand was part of the *value*  for one of the query string parameters, as written by the OP the `&` doesn't fall into that category as it's the separator between the currency parameter and the amount parameter. Plus, it doesn't explain the replacement of `currency` with `¤cy`

Comment: @Rob The browser interprets `&currency` as `&curren;cy` because `&curren;` is a defined HTML entity (see here: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). The "`¤`" character is the universal currency symbol.

Comment: So there's a browser bug going on then? (Re-)Interpreting `&currency` as `&curren;cy`, when it forms part of a query string (or even when it doesn't!) and then transforming it is a fairly hefty screwup

Comment: @Rob : Apparently it's not a bug, but rather exists to provide [backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15532252). HTML and JavaScript have always been very forgiving with incorrect code/syntax, so I guess the best would be to be strict and escape as much as possible in order to avoid things like this.