# text &REG is rendered as ® in html page

Tags: javascript, html, regex, extjs, render

I am trying to render a data from webhook to a form label say **"PRO&REGAIN"** is retrieved to a form. But it is rendered as PRO®AIN where **&REG** is considered as **®**. I know I can use encoding by using &amp ; instead *&* but I cannot do this change to backend while updating this data.

My question is, how do we render the data to the html page by ignoring such cases. I would like to display as like from backend.

I wonder the same above text is rendered properly as like in grid

Comment: Not familiar with extjs, but from pure DOM API you just set the `innerText` of the element, eg `element.innerText = "PRO&REGAIN"` (or create at text node) which doesn't process html entities

Comment: That shouldn't happen without `;` after `&reg`. Do browsers really try to "fix" this?

Comment: yes, HTML allows few characters are recognized without semicolon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532252/why-is-reg-being-rendered-as-without-the-bounding-semicolon

Comment: updating innerText worked for this case but how I cannot make this change to my entire application where ever this data is rendered. I am looking one stop solution to display the raw data by directly updating the value.

Comment: You could use `Ext.String.htmlEncode(value)` where you store the value on the front end, it will encode the `&` to `&amp;` for you so you dont have to do anything on the backend. Couldnt readily find an api method or setting that would tell extjs to just set text directly instead of html.